# Programming an ActiveX component in Visual Studio 2008 vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, activex, manual

anyone knows a good tutorial for programming ActiveX in Visual Studio 2008 for VC++? or the way to create methods and properties automatically, like the old Wizzard in VS6.0 did?

I was trying harder to find some info, but everything is for C#, VB, or it's explained for VS6.0 and not 2005 or newer :(

Thanx everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *do* take a hint from the lack of decent samples or tutorials.  If you really want to do this in C++ then check out a copy of Chris Sells' ATL Internals.  It is still in print afaik.  It contains a complete walkthrough for creating an ActiveX control using ATL.

Comment: Thanx Hans, I will check for it ;)